# does contention in a tthread dump means that the code written by developer is not efficient or can jvm internal threads can also cause contetion?

Tags: weblogic, thread-dump

Does contention only occurs if non daemon threads (application thread ) are trying to acquire the same lock or it can also occurs if daemon threads (jvm internal threads ) causes some issue ?

So, my main question is can daemon threads can cause contention ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes... WebLogic's threads are all daemon threads.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but I thought that daemon threads are mark by the keyword  daemon                                                                                             for example                                                                   SE_SOLR_PARALLEL_SEARCH_pool-14-thread-22" #4741 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=(any tid) nid=(any nid)  waiting on condition [lock]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)                                                                                                                 it is a non daemon thread

Comment: You are right, but it is not a weblogic thread... ExecuteThreads are all daemon threads.

Comment: so how does daemon thread cause contention . As contention is caused when a developer don't use synchronize block carefully thus causing a situation when one thread tries to aquire a lock that is held by another thread